How to save QLoRA fine tuned Llama-3-8B model on disk and use it without the need to download base-model again
I want to fine tune llama3-8B model and save the complete Fine-tuned model in local disk.
And, use the Fine-tuned model in local disk for prediction. I don't want to download the based model again from the HF.
Below is the code  , that is training well .
But I'm not able save the complete model offline.
https://github.com/Manjesh80/ml/blob/main/FineTune_V2.ipynb
I get the error adaptor-config missing ? Please advise on the proper way of saving of a Complete-Adapter-Model offline.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import bitsandbytes as bnb
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import transformers
from datasets import Dataset
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftConfig
from trl import SFTTrainer
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    TrainingArguments,
    pipeline,
    logging,
)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from peft.utils import TRANSFORMERS_MODELS_TO_LORA_TARGET_MODULES_MAPPING
import datasets
from peft import PeftModel
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM


def evaluate(y_true, y_pred):
    mapping = {"positive": 2, "neutral": 1, "none": 1, "negative": 0}

    def map_func(x):
        return mapping.get(x, 1)

    y_true = np.vectorize(map_func)(y_true)
    y_pred = np.vectorize(map_func)(y_pred)

    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.3f}")

    # Generate accuracy report
    unique_labels = set(y_true)  # Get unique labels

    for label in unique_labels:
        label_indices = [i for i in range(len(y_true)) if y_true[i] == label]
        label_y_true = [y_true[i] for i in label_indices]
        label_y_pred = [y_pred[i] for i in label_indices]
        accuracy = accuracy_score(label_y_true, label_y_pred)
        print(f"Accuracy for label {label}: {accuracy:.3f}")

    # Generate classification report
    class_report = classification_report(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
    print("\nClassification Report:")
    print(class_report)

    # Generate confusion matrix
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, labels=[0, 1, 2])
    print("\nConfusion Matrix:")
    print(conf_matrix)


def inference(pipe, prompt):
    result = pipe(prompt)
    answer = result[0]["generated_text"].split("=")[-1]
    return answer


def predict(X_test, model, tokenizer):
    y_pred = []
    pipe = pipeline(
        task="text-generation",
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        max_new_tokens=1,
        temperature=0.01,
        # device='cuda'
    )
    for i in tqdm(range(len(X_test))):
        prompt = X_test.iloc[i]["text"]
        answer = inference(pipe, prompt)

        if "positive" in answer:
            y_pred.append("positive")
        elif "negative" in answer:
            y_pred.append("negative")
        elif "neutral" in answer:
            y_pred.append("neutral")
        else:
            y_pred.append("none")
    return y_pred


def prepare_data():
    filename = "sent_train.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # df['text'] = df['input']
    df["sentiment"] = df["label"].map(
        {
            0: "negative",
            1: "positive",
            2: "neutral",
        }
    )

    X_train = list()
    X_test = list()
    for sentiment in ["positive", "neutral", "negative"]:
        train, test = train_test_split(
            df[df.sentiment == sentiment],
            train_size=300,
            test_size=300,
            random_state=42,
        )
        X_train.append(train)
        X_test.append(test)

    X_train = pd.concat(X_train).sample(frac=1, random_state=10)
    X_test = pd.concat(X_test)

    eval_idx = [
        idx for idx in df.index if idx not in list(train.index) + list(test.index)
    ]
    X_eval = df[df.index.isin(eval_idx)]
    X_eval = X_eval.groupby("sentiment", group_keys=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.sample(n=50, random_state=10, replace=True)
    )
    X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)

    X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train.apply(generate_prompt, axis=1), columns=["text"])
    X_eval = pd.DataFrame(X_eval.apply(generate_prompt, axis=1), columns=["text"])

    y_true = X_test.sentiment
    X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test.apply(generate_test_prompt, axis=1), columns=["text"])

    train_data = Dataset.from_pandas(X_train)
    eval_data = Dataset.from_pandas(X_eval)

    return train_data, eval_data, X_test, y_true


def generate_prompt(data_point):
    return f"""
            Analyze the sentiment of the news headline enclosed in square brackets, 
            determine if it is positive, neutral, or negative, and return the answer as 
            the corresponding sentiment label "positive" or "neutral" or "negative".

            [{data_point["text"]}] = {data_point["sentiment"]}
            """.strip()


def generate_test_prompt(data_point):
    return f"""
            Analyze the sentiment of the news headline enclosed in square brackets, 
            determine if it is positive, neutral, or negative, and return the answer as 
            the corresponding sentiment label "positive" or "neutral" or "negative".

            [{data_point["text"]}] = """.strip()


def init_model(model_name="meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B"):
    compute_dtype = getattr(torch, "float16")
    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
    )
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        device_map="auto",
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        trust_remote_code=True,
    )
    model.config.use_cache = False
    model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        trust_remote_code=True,
    )
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
    return model, tokenizer


def init_model_from_checkpoint(peft_model):
    model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        peft_model, device_map="auto", torch_dtype=torch.float16
    )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(peft_model)
    return model, tokenizer


##### TRAINING START

train_data, eval_data, X_test, y_true = prepare_data()

model, tokenizer = init_model()

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    r=64,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    # target_modules=target_modules
)

training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="logs",
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=8,  # 4
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
    save_steps=0,
    logging_steps=25,
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    weight_decay=0.001,
    fp16=True,
    bf16=False,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    max_steps=-1,
    warmup_ratio=0.03,
    group_by_length=True,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
    report_to="tensorboard",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
)

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=eval_data,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
    packing=False,
    max_seq_length=1024,
)

# Train model
trainer.train()

# Save trained model

output_dir = "results/adapter_fine_tune_llama3"
trainer.save_model(output_dir)

# SAVE MODEL TO LOCAL DIRECTORY
model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    output_dir,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
)
# Merge LoRA and base model and save
merged_model = model.merge_and_unload()
merged_dir = "results/final_fine_tune_llama3"
merged_model.save_pretrained(merged_dir, safe_serialization=True, max_shard_size="2GB")

## VERIFY SAVED MODEL

model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
  merged_dir,
  device_map="auto",
  torch_dtype=torch.float16
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(merged_dir)
y_pred = predict(X_test, model, tokenizer)
evaluate(y_true, y_pred)


